# Xml command line to open a url

Tags: kiosk-mode, windows-10-desktop

Can someone help me figure out what the command line is to open web link in xml, or more importantly, two url windows?

So if I wanted a kiosk to open two separate tabs while using only edge to do so.

I basically on need to know what the line would look like and any arguments I may need.

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have said syntax instead of command line..

Comment: Is having your questioned on stacked overflow edited a good thing? I feel like I should say thank you, but something inside says I’m a doofus.